# Can we validate dynamically generated values like datetime or any other number in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

Can we validate dynamically generated values like datetime or any other number in Karate DSL. If yes, could you please tell how do we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a JavaScript function replicating that dynamic value. and then do karate matching.

```
* def datetime = function(){code_generating_Date_time}
Then match datetime == response.datetime
```

Although i feel like generating the function should not be done, because it may become non-deterministic

Would suggest redesigning the test case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For example if the response is `{ id: 'a9f7a56b-8d5c-455c-9d13-808461d17b91', name: 'Billie' }`

You can assert this way:

```
{ id: '#string', name: 'Billie' }
```

Please read the documentation, because all of this is explained there: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching